# Deploying ASP.NET MVC to Plesk

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, plesk

I've been searching on the internet for a possible solution, but I have not been successful.

> How can I publish a ASP.NET MVC website on plesk?

I uploaded my whole solution in the file manager, but it does not find the right folder to read from as default.

Comment: Easiest way? Setup a publish profile that outputs to a local directory (e.g. `C:\MyWebsite`), publish the project, then upload the contents of the publish output to your web root.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I do that (I'm completely new to Plesk and setting up a website)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Plesk either, but assuming it's just a cpanel giving you file access, use it to upload the publish output. Otherwise, if you don't already, get FTP access to your site and leave Plesk out of it (and VisualStudio can publish to FTP natively).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put everything in your project folder onto Plesk File Manager's `httpdocs` folder. Thats it. Provided your hosting server is supporting MVC.

**ZIP WAY**

1. Also you can zip all the contents of your project folder.
2. Upload the zip file in Plesk's `httpdocs` folder inside File Manager.
3. Unzip the zip file there and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

In my Plesk I have to upload the site in a folder called httpdocs. My Plesk has two httpdocs folders, one inside the other. I use the first folder to deploy site in.